# DigitalOcean Permission denied (publickey) when adding new ssh keys to an existing droplet?

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, ssh-keys

Having issue adding new ssh keys to an existing droplet on Digital Ocean Ubuntu VM.
SSH key is added via Digial Ocean portal via browser.

When added SSH key first time from local Ubuntu machine it is working fine.

Next time trying to add SSH from MacOS machine, and unable to login even though 2nd SSH key was added successfully, and keep getting `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Checking on the remote Ubuntu droplet `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` can see `PubkeyAuthenthication yes`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There seem to be an issue with Digital Ocean web portal when adding 2nd SSH key. The portal show there are 2 SSH keys (`Settings\Security\SSH keys`).

However, checking `authorized_keys` file (`nano .ssh/authorized_keys`), only the 1st SSH key was there and the 2nd SSH key was not found.

Work a round fix was to login the Ubuntu server/droplet (using the working local Ubuntu machine for my case), and manually add 2nd SSH key (for MacOS machine) to `authorized_keys` file.

1. Server/Droplet Ubuntu:
   `nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. MacOS local machine:
   `cat .ssh/id_ed25519.pub` ( I used ed25519 type in this instance, change to whatever yours pub key is).
3. Paste the SSH pub key to `authorized_key` file.
4. Reload ssh on Ubuntu server/droplet: `systemctl reload ssh`

[image: image of authorized_keys file in nano editor]

Comment: This is exactly what I've done to fix the issue. I had 4 SSH keys. 3 were added through control panel, 1 was added by GitLab. I could not add the 5th SSH key using  control panel. I had to edit the authorized_keys file manually. I reported the issue to Digital Ocean in a ticket.

Comment: Any fix from digital ocean's side? I too am having a hard time adding all new ssh keys by logging in manually.

Comment: @theProcrastinator I've faced this issue so it's still reproducible

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the content of your public key corresponds to that in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score -3):

This case is happening to me,
I was unable to access "access" on my server dashboard.

This message appeared "{"id": "Forbidden", "message": "You are not authorized to perform this operation" }"

The solution: I deleted the instance and added another instance.